# Why is '' ^ 9 equal to 9?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I read about bitwise JavaScript operator [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29).

```
     9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
    14 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001110 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
14 ^ 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000000111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
```

Wondering how it is 9 for the below expression?

```
 '' ^ 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Rob W. I will be careful in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is a bitwise operator operating on signed 32-bit integers.
If an operand is not a 32-bit integer, it's converted to a signed 32-bit integer.

The behaviour of `ToInt32` is defined in [section 9.5 of the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) as "Let number be the result of calling `ToNumber` on the input argument.". The details of `ToNumber` are explained [here](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3). In practical terms, `ToNumber(x)` is equivalent to `+x`.

Then, 9.5 continues: "If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.".
The remaining steps of 9.5 boils down to "subtract/add 2<sup>32</sup> until the result is in the range [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>-1]".

Applied to `'' ^ 9`:

```
'' ^ 9
// ToInt32, step 1: ToNumber
0 ^ 9
// Bitwise XOR
9
```

Applied to `'string' ^ 9`:

```
'string' ^ 9
// ToInt32, step 1: ToNumber
NaN ^ 9
// ToInt32, step 2
0 ^ 9
// Bitwise XOR
9
```

Answer (score 4):

`''` converts to the number. `+'' === 0` and `0 ^ 9 = 9`

Comment: This answer is incomplete. `+` is **not** a "convert to integer" operation. So, although the answer seems plausible, it's missing fundamental intermediate steps.

Comment: thanks @Vitaliy Petrychuk. I tried with +'is not'^9 is also 9 but +'is not' is NaN

Comment: it's not surprising that 'some arbitrary string' is not a number in general.

Comment: @mightyuhu agreed but it is reply to Vitaliy Petrychuk. +NaN^9 is also 9. But I'm trying to understand based on the explanation mention in the MDN link (please refer question)